# How do I add a Class to Specific Parent Elements ONLY if the Child Container has Content

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

This may look like a duplicate thread but it is a little more complicated than the ones I have read.

I have dynamic content being pulled into a vue slick carousel, which links with another carousel to act as an anchor navigation (using asNavFor). the other carousel I am linking to has a ton of items (let's go with 30) that are all separated by categories. In my navigation carousel i want to only have buttons for the categories, not for each item (4 categories). the v-for i have created only shows content if it has a categoryName (v-if="categoryName") so out of the 30 slides it is dynamically pulling it only shows 4 (Great!). NOW, i need to hide all the empty slides somehow because i need to keep the index of the slides so that it brings you to the correct slide in the other carousel.

Currently I have:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#anchor-inner')
    var anchorIndex = 0
    var length = anchors.length

    for (; anchorIndex < length; anchorIndex++) {
      if (anchors[anchorIndex].innerHTML.length === 0) {
        console.log('here')
      }
    }
```

this at least finds the slides that have nothing in it, but now how do i only hide the slides that are "empty"? I need to hide the actual "slick-slide" or even set to have zero width so that it doesn't take up space on my page. Is this even possible to do?

EDIT
there is the slick-slide container which adds a child div, followed by my 'anchor-inner" (which is where i have my v-for to create the array) and then my anchor-button that is only shown if it has the category name.

```
<VueSlickCarousel class="anchor-carousel">
   <div id="anchor-inner" v-for="(id, index) in updatedArray" :key="index">
      <button id="anchor-button" v-if="id.catTitle">{{id.catTitle}}</button>
   </div>
</VueSlickCarousel>
```

Here is a quick example once the slides are dynamically created

```
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"><button class="anchor-heading">Category 1</button></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"><button class="anchor-heading">Category 2</button></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"><button class="anchor-heading">Category 3</button></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"><button class="anchor-heading">Category 4</button></div></div></div>
<div class="slick-slide"><div><div class="anchor-inner"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but i think you get it because you had some issues in your code :)

```js
var slickSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-slide');

for (var i = 0; i < slickSlide.length; i++) {
  if (slickSlide[i].children.length === 0) {
    slickSlide[i].remove();
  }
}
```

EDIT:
You have the search for empty divs and remove them until no empty is find because after removing an empty the parent is empty the next time.

In this example i wrapped all slick-slide elments into a `.slide-wrapper` class

```js
var slickSlide = document.querySelector('.slide-wrapper').getElementsByTagName('div');

function removeAllEmptys() {
    var divCount = slickSlide.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < slickSlide.length; i++) {
    if (slickSlide[i].children.length === 0) {
      slickSlide[i].remove();
    }
  }
  
  if (divCount !== slickSlide.length) {
    removeAllEmptys();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 
}

removeAllEmptys();
```

This will only keep the `.slick-slide` elements with the category in it

Comment: okay that's awesome : ) i just wanted to clarify a little more. What if my slick slide had multiple inner containers.  <div class="slick-slide"><div></div></div>  does the .children only work if it has absolutely nothing inside or if there is another div inside of it that is also empty will it still work?

Comment: I just made an edit to my question to show it is more complex. That is my fault for simplifying it too much

Comment: I have been trying to implement this, which seems to be grabbing all the divs in my console, but it says [object HTMLDivElement], do you know what this means in this scenario?